# How to break a column into two in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, split

This is how cells in a column of the CSV looks like

```
[u"ABC||||'ABCDadfasf||||'random something', 'another random']
[u"ABCD||||'ABCDadfasf||||'random somethingadf', 'another random adsd']
[u"ABDC||||'ABCDasdadfasf||||'random something random', 'another something random']
```

`

I want to break it like below. Split based on ('||||')

```
Col 1      Col 2          Col 3 
[u"ABC    ABCDadfasf    'random something', 'another random']
[u"ABCD   ABCDadfasf    'random somethingadf', 'another random adsd']
[u"ABDC   ABCDasdadfasf 'random something random', 'another something random']
```

This is what I tried

```
Cov = pd.read_csv("path to CSV.csv", sep='||||', names = ["col 1", "col 2", "col 3"], engine = 'python')
```

it does not show any error but the column is not split.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\` for escape `|` because special regex character:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""[u"ABC||||'ABCDadfasf||||'random something', 'another random']
[u"ABCD||||'ABCDadfasf||||'random somethingadf', 'another random adsd']
[u"ABDC||||'ABCDasdadfasf||||'random something random', 'another something random']"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep=r"\|\|\|\|", names = ["col 1", "col 2", "col 3"], engine = 'python') 

print (df)
     col 1           col 2                                              col 3
0   [u"ABC     'ABCDadfasf              'random something', 'another random']
1  [u"ABCD     'ABCDadfasf      'random somethingadf', 'another random adsd']
2  [u"ABDC  'ABCDasdadfasf  'random something random', 'another something ...

#temp=u"""
```